# Visual Studio 2015 exit code 0xE0434352

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a build script which starts Visual Studio from a command line as follows:

```
devenv.exe <project file> /Rebuild "Release" /Project <project name> /UseEnv /Out <log file>
```

On completion the script checks the exit code from Visual Studio.

We have updated from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015. Most of the projects compile without problems, but some exit with the code 0xE0434352, which I believe is System.InvalidOperationException.

The windows event log shows two entries:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564ea97e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.19045, time stamp: 0x56258f05
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0xb64
Faulting application start time: 0x01d131c68bdc0db0
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: cb600c61-9db9-11e5-abfc-005056c00008
```

and

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation+<>c.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__18_0(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

The projects are VB and C# Windows Forms projects. It is not happening with C++ projects.

So far as I can tell, the components are always built correctly and the exception occurs on closing visual studio. I have modified our script to ignore this specific error, but that doesn't seem like a great solution.

Can anybody suggest how to fix this problem?

Comment: 0xE0434352 is the exception code for managed exceptions, could be anything.  That stack trace is *very* generic, could be anything but add-ins are always on the top of the list.  You should be using msbuild.exe instead.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. Is there a convenient way to build a visual studio project in a given configuration using MSBuild?

Comment: capture a crash dump. run **procdump -ma i C:\localdumps** to register procdump (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) as post mortem debugger. When you get a new crash, a dmp is written to C:\localdumps. Open this dmp with Windbg (part of the Debugging tools from the Windows SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and run **!analyze -v**. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: I can't think of an inconvenient way.

Comment: @HansPassant, You are right. I have tried it out, it does not crash and it is significantly faster than using devenv. The command line is a bit cryptic (particularly the logging options) but I can handle it. Actually, I had an old prejudice based on the build utility which used to be in the Windows DDK, which I never liked, but that must have been in the last century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that are all normal projects you build you don't need devenv to do that work for you.

Simply use [msbuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).

I think this commandline should get you started:

```
msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release [your .sln or .csproj or .vbproj]
```

Which instructs msbuild to process the [Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) target and set the [Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164288.aspx) named Configuration to Release

Notice how you can either msbuild the complete solution or single projects this way. The only exception is for projecttypes that are only known to Visual Studio and not to msbuild. For earlier versions of VS that was true for the Setup projecttype. You couldn't build that one without running devenv.

Comment: It is more difficult than it appears. I found that I must also specify the Platform on the command line, which was not necessary with the DevEnv command. Previously, the build script did not have this information, which required some work to fix. Most of our projects do not use Project Dependencies - which might or might not be good. The few projects which did caused problems, even when I used BuildProjectReferences=false. Eventually I replaced them with DLL references. I still find MSBuild can be hard to understand.